Help identify a film with a class of teenaged kids touring a secure facility/fortress
I saw a trailer last year (I think) which showed a group of teenage/college kids walking around what look liked a secure underground facility. It didn't look like it was set in the future or anything, just a very strong fortress of some kind. 
From recollection (which may be inaccurate), the kids looked like they all knew each other (perhaps a class trip), and they were all dressed in modern clothes as any teenager of today would. 
I think there was an older figure (either a teacher or someone who worked at the facility) explaining the aspects of the fortress which made it sound like it would be impossible to penetrate (or escape from). The kids were more stunned about the scale of the fortress than any real fear of being imprisoned inside, although there was a sense that there was something sinister about the fortress that the kids aren't being told. 
I know this is incredibly vague, but does anyone know what this movie was called, or have any suggestions of what it could be? 

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Any other plot details or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

Just found out (with assistance) that the movie I was asking about is After the Dark. It came out in 2013, not last year like I thought, and the plot is quite different from what I outlined. 
For anyone interested, here is the plot:
"When the last day of school comes for a group of students in a philosophy class, their instructor, Mr. Zimit, challenges them to different sorts of exercises that take place in a post-nuclear apocalyptic world. While there, they each get chosen professions and have to decide whether who is valuable or not because the bunker they will be staying in for a year has only enough oxygen for 10 people. Mr. Zimit challenges them in different rounds to see how they could survive. Issues arise when they notice Mr. Zimit is disruptive to the game."
On seeing the trailer again (there are several different ones) and reading reviews and comments, it doesn't sound like it's a great film, but at least I now know the answer to something that's been bugging me for the past few days.
Thanks all!!

Glad you figured it out!  Be sure to accept your answer so that it's marked as solved on the site!

Could it be 'The Maze Runner'?
Trailer here
It's based on a series of young adult books, and came out last year. Plot description from Wikipedia:
'The story follows sixteen-year-old Thomas, portrayed by Dylan O'Brien, who wakes up in a rusty elevator with no memory of himself except his name. Later he learns that he's been delivered to the middle of an intricate maze, along with a slew of other boys, who have been trying to find their way out of the ever-changing labyrinth while establishing a functioning society. '

Thanks Tom. It does sound like The Maze Runner from my description, but alas, it's not unfortunately. Really appreciate your help though!!

Not to worry. I'll keep thinking, but good luck with your search for the answer!
